# Need help so its less characters in total

Tags: java

So i ended up getting it down to 139 once all spaces are removed now i just need 8 more to beat my teacher any recomendations welcomed thanks also i moved it back into intellij just so its easier for me to change

package com.company;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    for(int i=1;i++<100;)System.out.println(i%15==0?"Code Dojo":i%5==0?"Dojo":i%3==0?"Code":""+i);}}
```

Comment: Remove as many spaces as you can. Note: Your main function MUST be called main. Additionally, you would want to create another method to print.

Comment: Ya sorry i have that changed at my computer at school, this was just the version i had on my flash drive and we dont count spaces,my teacher gave me a hint saying there was a way to shorten it with my argument he said he's only using one somehow

Comment: 148 characters. `public class x{public static void main(String[] a){for(int i=1;i<101;i++)System.out.println(i%15==0?"Code Dojo":i%5==0?"Dojo":i%3==0?"Code":""+i);}}`

Comment: I tried using that earlier two days ago and i didnt understand how it worked , i just learned methods last week

Comment: I have a question, does name of the Class also include in the count? Also is the argument in main needed to be there?

Comment: ya the name of class is included , and the argument in main needs to be there

Comment: im using command line so i changed it to x

Comment: Don't forget to tell your teacher that you cheated by asking for expert help on StackOverflow in your efforts to beat him.

Comment: `for(int i=1;i++<100;)` means that on first iteration, `i` is 2. That doesn't seem correct. For last iteration, `i` is 100. --- In the original post, you had `for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++)`, which iterates `i` from 0 to 100, both inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm down to this answer.
remove the `public` in main class
remove extra `""+`
Total remove character 9

```
class X {public static void main(String[] a) {for(int i=1;i++<100;)System.out.println(i%15==0?"Code Dojo":i%5==0?"Dojo":i%3==0?"Code":i);}}
```

Well I think its not also part of the rules where we fully utilize the arguments

```
class X{public static void main(String[] x){for(int i=1;i++<100;)System.out.println(i%15==0?x[0]:i%5==0?x[1]:i%3==0?x[2]:i);}}
```

And run the code like this:

```
java X "Code Dojo" "Dojo" "Code"
```

Here you go my best answer.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] a) {` < -remove space here

Comment: Also, remove the space to the right in here `class X `<-`{`

Comment: @FailingCoder Flamey Games said they don't count the spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use `interface` to get rid of `public`, but honestly you should check out [the code golf StackExchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages). Not going to space out the code except for those required to compile, because spaces are ugly in golfing.

```
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;++i<100;)System.out.println(i%3!=0?i%5!=0?i:”Dojo”:i%5==0?”Code Dojo”:”Code”);}}
```

Do beware that the quotation marks in the code won’t compile because I typed this out on my phone, so you’ll have to replace them.